# undefined is not an object after updating react-navigation to v3

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

i updated my react-native testproject yesterday to the new version of react-navigation v3, but now when i run the project i got this red error screen with the error Message

undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RNGestureHandlerModule.State')

[image]

The thing is i created a new and clean project after hours of cleaning node_modules folder and updating and so on but the error wont disappear.
Today i uploaded the mini project on snack and everything is fine.. no errors and the mini test app runs almost perfectly -> https://snack.expo.io/@snak3/test-with-react-native

But on the normal "react-native run-ios" the error wont go away. I also uploaded the project to github: https://github.com/Rockatweb/test-react-native

Can anyone help me with this? I dont know what the problem is :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solve this problem using below commands:**

```
Step1: npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler

Step2: react-native link react-native-gesture-handler

Step3: Killall node -9

Step4: Delete app from simulator or imulator

Step5: Run app from Xcode or Android studio
```

Answer (score 3):

I have this issue too : helped for me :

Do this command in your project may help you :

```
react-native link react-native-gesture-handler
```

Comment: it looks like that the error is gone now. But now i have another problem. Now there is another Error Screen with the following Error: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). Do you have a solution for this too?

Comment: i restarted the whole ios simulator and bundeling process and now it seems to work. Thanks :)

Comment: Your Welcom my friend 

Comment: Your answer is right too, but his is more complete. So if others have this problem both answers are correct :) Sadly, i cannot accept both :(

Comment: Sry Dude, im new to react-native. And for me its better when there are more informations about a solution. Thats the big problem with react, sometimes there are no good or complete documentations for problems, bugs or workarounds. And i think i am not alone with this problem :) As i said, your answer is also good :)